# Xampp showing cross signs at its services

Tags: php, wordpress, server, xampp, localhost

When I open the XAMPP control panel it shows a cross sign ❌ at its services tab. On hover, it says **Is installed as a windows service?** and when I clicked, it says **Click to install apache service** and after installing it shows tick mark ✅ sign. I'm using XAMPP for years, I just re-installed a XAMPP and this time it behaves differently than usual. If anyone experienced this issue, please let me know.

[image]

XAMMP version: v3.3.0

Operating System: Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Before you click on start click the cross sign. it shows a dialogue box to install the Apache, MySQL, etc. so click ok and you can get rid of this error. the cross sign will be removed and installed properly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jP9GR.png)